# Decoding Ceramic Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, ceramic

How could I decode this capacitor?
MEXICO is written on the other side and it's in a speaker.
[image]

Comment: Is there any marking on the other side?

Comment: MEXICO, nothing more

Comment: can you tell where that component is placed?

Comment: Are you sure it's a capacitor and not a MOV?

Comment: If not a MOV the PTC is also possible.

Comment: Can you add a schematic of the parts around it?

Comment: Not like any capacitor I ever saw.

Comment: its a resettable fuse

Comment: and how can i decode the print?

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

it is a PPTC (Polymeric Positive Temperature Coefficient) which is a re-settable fuse

the exact parameters we can calculate if we gets its datasheet

since the part number and marking on part will be different.